# Error host desconocido envío de correos Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

estoy ennviando correos con la librería de email Codeigniter, he hecho las configuraciones necesarias, pero estoy teniendo este error:

```
Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido.
```

Y esta es mi función para enviar el correo:

```
$config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_user' => '******',
        'smtp_pass' => '******',
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'mailtype' => 'text',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE,
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'newline' => '\r\n'
    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->from('*****');
    $this->email->subject('Asunto del correo');
    $this->email->message('Hola desde correo');
    $this->email->to($email_address);
    if($this->email->send(FALSE)){
        echo "enviado<br/>";
        echo $this->email->print_debugger(array('headers'));
    }else {
        echo "fallo <br/>";
        echo "error: ".$this->email->print_debugger(array('headers'));
    }
```

Ya probé cambiando el puerto 465 a 587 pero es lo mismo, agradecería si alguien pudiera ayudarme!

Comment: Por qué estás poniendo ese prefijo `ssl://` en el host? SSL es un protocolo pero de otra capa, así que la URL no se va a resolver con eso ahí puesto.

Comment: @Alfabravo tal vez una posible respuesta en ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library

Comment: ¿Tienes habilitada la extensión `php_openssl` en el servidor? Adicionalmente, `\r\n` debería estar encerrado entre comillas dobles para que se interprete como `retorno de carro + salto de línea`.

Comment: @JuanRivera Ah! ok, la librería lo soporta y lo interpreta.